# Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0 when parsing a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

```
https.get('example.com/phpfilethatechoesandimtryingtograbtheecho.php', (res) => {
   console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
   onsole.log('headers:', res.headers);

   res.on('data', (d) => {
       return msg.reply(JSON.parse(d));
   });

}).on('error', (e) => {
   throw e;
});
```

I am trying to grab the echo from that php website. I tried Express with app.get() but it couldn't console.log(). I don't know why it didn't error anything with Express but couldn't output.

This thing I'm searching answer for works when I output the "d" using `process.stdout.write()`. By "d" I mean the d that is here `res.on('data', (**d**))`.

I also managed to get this `{"type":"Buffer","data":[103,75,68,101,54,78,109,77,117,65,83,67,52,86,81,88,113,106,101,81,77,86,71,66,90,68,112,100,71,76,103,51]}` when I stringified the "d" and replied to my message on Discord.

Comment: Note that this question was nearly unreadable prior to my edit. Most languages use paragraphs, including English, and without them people will tend to skip the question. Make life easier for your readers!

Answer (score 0):

The `res` in your `https.get` is a Stream. Now stream has multiple events, [`data`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) is one of them. When you listen for `data` event what you get is a **chunk of data**.

So for a JSON file that you are getting from your server (in this case your php file) `d` is part of it not all of it.

There is one more event called [`end`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end), which is, to put it simply, fired when there is no data left in the stream (means all of the data is sent to you). So you need to use `end` event to actually process the data as all of the data is there with you now.

I am adding a code snippet that might help you:

```
https
  .get("url", res => {
    console.log("statusCode:", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers:", res.headers);
    let responseData = "";
    res.on("data", d => {
      //store the chunks in a variable
      responseData += d;
    });
    res.on("end", () => {
      //here now you have all the data, so parse the data
      msg.reply(JSON.parse(responseData));
    });
  })
  .on("error", e => {
    throw e;
  });
```